# Angularfir2 database

Tags: firebase, nativescript, angularfire2

In setuping angularfire2 documentation when I import AngularFireDatabaseModule,ngularFireAuthModule in ng module there is this bug :

cannot compile tns_modules/angularfire2/database.js.

What is the problem?

app.module.ts :

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from 'angularfire2/auth';

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";





@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  imports: [NativeScriptModule,
     AngularFireDatabaseModule, 
    AngularFireAuthModule,
  ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: hmm.. strange.. what is your "ng -v" output? and what is your angularfire2 version?

Comment: angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3
node: 7.10.0                                                                                                                       angularfire2 version :4.0.0-rc.0

Comment: try to install node version 6.10.3, using `nvm install 6.10.3` and then `nvm use 6.10.3` and also update the angular/cli with the latest version

Comment: I did.But it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

@Gandom as far as I saw the angularfire2 is not compatible with NativeScript as it depends on som browser specific modules. To use Firebase in NativeScript I would recommend using [nativescript-plugin-firebase](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase)